# How to do redirect 301 between url https using Istio Virtual Service

Tags: ssl, istio, http-status-code-301, http-redirect, istio-gateway

I'm trying to perform a 301 redirect for some requests using Istio's Gateway with VirtualService. I've done everything, and it works perfectly if the request is over HTTP, but it doesn't work for HTTPS.

The scenario is as follows: I have an address https://www.myhost.com/oldpath, and I want to redirect it to https://myhost.com/newpath. I have several URLs that need this change to the host without "www." and also change the path.

Please note that in my Gateway, I'm using ManagedCertificate, which generated the certificate within the Google Cloud Platform. Since I can't create a secret to pass the tls attribute of the Gateway, I configured it as PASSTHROUGH.

When my certificate didn't have the domain with "www.," it worked. However, when I created the ManagedCertificate including both domains with and without "www.," the redirection stopped working.
Below are my files.

```yaml
#managed-certificate-file

apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1
kind: ManagedCertificate
metadata:
  name: managed-cert
spec:
  domains:
    - myhost.com
    - www.myhost.com
```

```yaml
---
#ingress-file
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: my-ingress
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.global-static-ip-name: my-external-ip-gcp
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "gce"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.allow-http: "true"
    networking.gke.io/v1beta1.FrontendConfig: my-frontend-config
spec:
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: my-important-service
      port:
        name: http
---

#frontend-config-file

apiVersion: networking.gke.io/v1beta1
kind: FrontendConfig
metadata:
  name: my-frontend-config
spec:
  sslPolicy: my-ssl-policy
  redirectToHttps:
    enabled: false
```

```yaml
---
#gateway-file

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: my-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway 
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "*"
  - port:
      number: 443
      name: https
      protocol: HTTPS
    hosts:
    - "*"
    tls:
      mode: PASSTHROUGH
```

```yaml
---
#virtual-service file

apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: myhost-redirect
spec:
  hosts:
    - "www.myhost.com"
  gateways:
    - my-gateway

  http:
    - match:
        - uri:
            exact: /register
      redirect:
        uri: /sign-up
        authority: myhost.com
        scheme: "https"

    - match:
        - uri:
            exact: /get-my-password
      redirect:
        uri: /password-reset
        authority: myhost.com
        scheme: "https"
```